# Composite manager for i3wm

Tags: desktop-environment, i3, compton, composite

Is there any composite manager to use with i3 except Compton. I am having serious tearing and ghosting. I have been using various Compton configuration none of which are working. So if there is a composite manager which I can use with i3wm or if there is a workaround this please let me know.

Following Compton configuration I had tried,

[Official sample configuration](https://github.com/chjj/compton/blob/master/compton.sample.conf)

[Compton config for tearing problem](http://duncanlock.net/blog/2013/06/07/how-to-switch-to-compton-for-beautiful-tear-free-compositing-in-xfce/)

**Hardware Information:**

**VGA:**

`[root@arif arif]# lspci -v -s $(lspci | grep -i 'vga\|3d\|2d' | awk '{print $1}')
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device d000
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Memory at f6000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915`

**Memory**: 16GB
**Processor:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
**OS:** Centos 7
`

Comment: Comton and i3 work together flawlessly. You could add some information about your video hardware and driver.

Comment: Added hardware information.